# Search history from multiple bash session only when Ctrl + R is used, not when arrow keys are used

Tags: bash, command-history

I usually have multiple bash sessions open. I want the history from multiple session to appear when doing a search (with Ctrl + R). When arrow keys are used only the current bash session's history should appear.

Many stackexchange questions relates to storing the history from multiple session. I already use it but my need is little different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there is not a clean solution to your problem without reimplementing some key component of how the shell (bash in this case) deals with history. Below is a solution that maintains your local history so that the arrows work as expected. Ctrl-r in turn is bound to searching your global history. The solution depends on an excellent utility for searching through your history called [hh](https://github.com/dvorka/hstr). Below are the instructions to set everything up.

Add to a startup file either `~/.profile`,`~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`:

```
# Whenever a command is executed, write it to a global history
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a ~/.bash_history.global"

# On C-r run the swap_history_reverse.sh script, 
bind -x '"\C-r": "~/swap_history_reverse.sh"'
```

Create the following script `~/swap_history_reverse.sh`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# Point hh to global history
export HISTFILE=~/.bash_history.global

# Reverse search
hh

# Restore local history
export HISTFILE=~/.bash_history
```

Make the script executable:

```
chmod +x ~/swap_history_reverse.sh
```

Install `hh`, see [INSTALL](https://github.com/dvorka/hstr/blob/master/INSTALLATION.md#installation).

Once everything is in place, open up a new shell and give it a run.